# insert select issue mysqli php

Tags: php, apache, mysqli, mariadb

I got a very simple mysqli statement in php 7.1 on apache web-server:

```
INSERT INTO user SELECT * FROM user_geloescht WHERE id = '294930';
```

This should copy a user into a separate table for deleted users. But when I run the script, nothing happens to the database. When I copy the statement to my mariadb cli it works without any error.

I already looked for a similar "SHOW columns from user" and ... user_geloescht output but that doesnt fix it.

I would give you some debugging but the query result is just true -> so no error.

What can be wrong or what output can I supply to you?

Edit: as i wrote in the comments - it works when I perform an code-exit immediatly after the insert-select so it may be something about commiting.

A delete on the user-id in the user-table which is performed after the insert-select is also without any effect

I will keep you up-to date after I tried forced commits.

Putting PHP-Code isn't that easy caused by my class-structure and handling of arguments between some functions

Comment: Please use the debugging [function](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) available to you to help us help you and include all your code.

Comment: post the php code please

Comment: Are You sure that the "user_geloescht" really contains user id "294930"?

Comment: Thank you for you fast hints. In my tries to build a debugging for you, I noticed that when i perform an exit immediatly after my insert ... select -> it works fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I think i need more coffee :D.

The problem was that everythink worked as it should do but I handled it all wrong.

The insert-select is fine but my delete pointed on the wrong table, so i copied the user from user_geloescht-table to user-table but deleted the copied user on the user-table and not on user_geloescht-table.

Thanks to all your effort -> I will request some holiday :D

Answer (score 0):

this is the syntax:

```
INSERT INTO user (name)SELECT name FROM user WHERE id = 294930
```

assuming you only have a column in a user table called name. and I don't know what is that user_geloescht mean for. is that a table or a column name.

Comment: There are two tables: user and user_geloescht which both have the same structure with (its history's fault) have about 190 columns so I wouldn't name each column in the statement, its just the same structure

Comment: INSERT INTO this_table_archive (*) SELECT * FROM this_table WHERE id = 294930; just make sure the columns of the 2 table are identical. the same name and number of columns.